# Error with ExecuteQuery in Documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I´m trying to execute a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM c
```

To execute this query I have this code

```
var urlDocument = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, collectionName);
        using (var client = GetDocumentClientAsync())
        {
            var taskQuery = Task.Run(
                () => client.CreateDocumentQuery(urlDocument, query,
                new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = 10,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false,
                    MaxBufferedItemCount = 100,
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
                }).ToList());
            var querydb = taskQuery.Result;
```

I tried without the auxiliary Task and with other forms (already without the FeedOptions). 
I always receive this error:

```
    System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Se han producido uno o varios errores.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       en Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       en DocumentDbApi.DocumentDbRepository.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<ExecuteQuery>b__0() en D:\Documentos\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatabaseStudio\DocumentDbApi\DocumentDbRepository.cs:línea 181
       en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
       en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException: 
       ActivityId=80272f2f-03fc-424f-b6cd-089a5e3e03ef
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":0,"end":0},"code":"SC1002","message":"Syntax error, unexpected end-of-file."}]}
ActivityId: 80272f2f-03fc-424f-b6cd-089a5e3e03ef, Request URI: /apps/39810a5b-058a-4edb-9502-8ddd6d977eec/services/9170e8c4-983b-45d5-8bdf-5eb5b1400da7/partitions/ed4d1123-d7c5-4d3c-ad13-320875aa8507/replicas/131247462173547477s
       RequestCharge=1
       Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client
```

I don´t have problems to do simple read document by id, inserts, updates, replaces, deletes... only with sql queries.

Comment: What's the query you're sending in? 

I'm unable to replicate your problem. Code https://gist.github.com/Ulriksen/ced1c81433802f566ad9ff9ef628613c runs fine.

Comment: Thanks.It´s the same query "SELECT * FROM c". My application already runs if it´s a console execution, but doesn´t run when is a winforms application.

Comment: Opsssss, the problem was the library of Documentdb and my framework. The code runs fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed a Documentdb client dll for other framework version. Now the code runs fine.
Thanks

Comment: Just curious, which framework dll you installed earlier that gave you this error?

Comment: I installed framework 2.0 in a project of windows forms and 4.6.1 in the azure project.